# OpenSwan IPSec phase #2 complications

Tags: linux, security, vpn, ipsec, openswan

Phase #1 (**IKE**) succeeds without any problems (verified at the target host).
Phase #2 (**IPSec**), however, is erroneous at some point (apparently due to misconfiguration on localhost).

This should be an **IPSec**-only connection. I am using **OpenSwan** on **Debian**. The error log reads the following (the actual IP-addr. of the remote endpoint has been modified):

> pluto[30868]: "x" #2: initiating Quick Mode PSK+ENCRYPT+PFS+UP+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK {using isakmp#1 msgid:5ece82ee proposal=AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_160 pfsgroup=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH22}
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #1: ignoring informational payload, type NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN msgid=00000000
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #1: received and ignored informational message
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #1: the peer proposed: 0.0.0.0/0:0/0 -> 0.0.0.0/0:0/0
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #3: responding to Quick Mode proposal {msgid:a4f5a81c}
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #3:     us: 192.168.1.76<192.168.1.76>[+S=C]
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #3:   them: 222.222.222.222<222.222.222.222>[+S=C]===10.196.0.0/17
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #3: transition from state STATE_QUICK_R0 to state STATE_QUICK_R1
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #3: STATE_QUICK_R1: sent QR1, inbound IPsec SA installed, expecting QI2
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #1: ignoring informational payload, type NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN msgid=00000000
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #1: received and ignored informational message
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #3: next payload type of ISAKMP Hash Payload has an unknown value: 97 X
>   pluto[30868]: "x" #3: malformed payload in packet
>   pluto[30868]: | payload malformed after IV

I am behind **NAT** and this is all coming from **wlan2**. Here are the details:

> default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan2  proto static
>   169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan2  scope link  metric 1000
>   192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.76  metric 2

Output of **ipsec verify**:

> Checking your system to see if IPsec got installed and started correctly:
>   Version check and ipsec on-path                                 [OK]
>   Linux Openswan U2.6.37/K3.2.0-24-generic (netkey)
>   Checking for IPsec support in kernel                            [OK]
>    SAref kernel support                                           [N/A]
>    NETKEY:  Testing XFRM related proc values                      [OK]
>           [OK]
>           [OK]
>   Checking that pluto is running                                  [OK]
>    Pluto listening for IKE on udp 500                             [OK]
>    Pluto listening for NAT-T on udp 4500                          [OK]
>   Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding            [OK]
>   Checking NAT and MASQUERADEing                                  [OK]
>   Checking for 'ip' command                                       [OK]
>   Checking /bin/sh is not /bin/dash                               [WARNING]
>   Checking for 'iptables' command                                 [OK]
>   Opportunistic Encryption Support                                [DISABLED]

This is what happens when I run **ipsec auto --up x**:

> 104 "x" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate
>   003 "x" #1: received Vendor ID payload [RFC 3947] method set to=109
>   106 "x" #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
>   003 "x" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Cisco-Unity]
>   003 "x" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
>   003 "x" #1: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [502099ff84bd4373039074cf56649aad]
>   003 "x" #1: received Vendor ID payload [XAUTH]
>   003 "x" #1: NAT-Traversal: Result using RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal): i am NATed
>   108 "x" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
>   004 "x" #1: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=OAKLEY_PRESHARED_KEY cipher=aes_128 prf=oakley_sha group=modp1024}
>   117 "x" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: initiate
>   010 "x" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: retransmission; will wait 20s for response
>   010 "x" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: retransmission; will wait 40s for response
>   031 "x" #2: max number of retransmissions (2) reached STATE_QUICK_I1.  No acceptable response to our first Quick Mode message: perhaps peer likes no proposal
>   000 "x" #2: starting keying attempt 2 of at most 3, but releasing whack

More debug info from **ipsec auto --status**:

> 000 using kernel interface: netkey
>   000 interface lo/lo ::1
>   000 interface wlan2/wlan2 192.168.1.76
>   000 interface wlan2/wlan2 192.168.1.76
>   000 %myid = (none)
>   000 debug raw+crypt+parsing+emitting+control+lifecycle+klips+dns+oppo+controlmore+pfkey+nattraversal+x509+dpd+oppoinfo
>   000
>   000 virtual_private (%priv):
>   000 - allowed 2 subnets: 10.196.0.0/17, 192.168.1.0/24
>   000 - disallowed 0 subnets:
>   000 WARNING: Disallowed subnets in virtual_private= is empty. If you have
>   000          private address space in internal use, it should be excluded!
>   000
>   000 stats db_ops: {curr_cnt, total_cnt, maxsz} :context={0,4,36} trans={0,4,1536} attrs={0,4,2048}
>   000
>   000 "x": 192.168.1.0/24===192.168.1.76[+S=C]...222.222.222.222<222.222.222.222>[+S=C]===10.196.0.0/17; unrouted; eroute owner: #0
>   000 "x":     myip=unset; hisip=unset;
>   000 "x":   ike_life: 28800s; ipsec_life: 28800s; rekey_margin: 540s; rekey_fuzz: 100%; keyingtries: 3
>   000 "x":   policy: PSK+ENCRYPT+PFS+UP+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK+lKOD+rKOD; prio: 24,17; interface: wlan2;
>   000 "x":   dpd: action:clear; delay:0; timeout:0;
>   000 "x":   newest ISAKMP SA: #0; newest IPsec SA: #0;
>   000 "x":   ESP algorithms wanted: AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_000; pfsgroup=DH22(22); flags=-strict
>   000 "x":   ESP algorithms loaded: AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_160

Even more debug info (**plutodebug="all"**) coming from **/var/log/auth.log**:

> pluto[26439]: | peer client is subnet 0.0.0.0/0
>   pluto[26439]: | peer client protocol/port is 0/0
>   pluto[26439]: | our client is subnet 0.0.0.0/0
>   pluto[26439]: | our client protocol/port is 0/0
>   pluto[26439]: "x" #1: the peer proposed: 0.0.0.0/0:0/0 -> 0.0.0.0/0:0/0
>   pluto[26439]: | find_client_connection starting with x
>   pluto[26439]: |   looking for 0.0.0.0/0:0/0 -> 0.0.0.0/0:0/0
>   pluto[26439]: |   concrete checking against sr#0 192.168.1.0/24 -> 10.196.0.0/17
>   pluto[26439]: |    match_id a=222.222.222.222
>   pluto[26439]: |             b=222.222.222.222
>   pluto[26439]: |    results  matched
>   pluto[26439]: |   trusted_ca called with a=(empty) b=(empty)
>   pluto[26439]: |   fc_try trying x:0.0.0.0/0:0/0 -> 0.0.0.0/0:0/0 vs x:192.168.1.0/24:0/0 -> 10.196.0.0/17:0/0
>   pluto[26439]: |    our client(192.168.1.0/24) not in our_net (0.0.0.0/0)
>   pluto[26439]: |   fc_try concluding with none [0]
>   pluto[26439]: |   fc_try x gives none
>   pluto[26439]: | find_host_pair: comparing to 192.168.1.76:500 222.222.222.222:500
>   pluto[26439]: |   checking hostpair 192.168.1.0/24 -> 10.196.0.0/17 is not found
>   pluto[26439]: |   concluding with d = none
>   pluto[26439]: | using (something - hopefully the IP we or they are NAT'ed to) for transport mode connection "x"

I have enabled **NAT** traversal in **ipsec.conf** accordingly. Here are the settings relative to the connection in question:

> version   2.0
>
> config setup
>
> > plutoopts="--perpeerlog"
> >      plutoopts="--interface=wlan2"
> >      dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
> >      nat_traversal=yes
> >      virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12
> >      oe=off
> >      protostack=netkey
>
> conn x
>
> > ```
> > authby=secret  
> > pfs=yes  
> > auto=add  
> > phase2alg=aes256-sha1;dh22  
> > keyingtries=3  
> > ikelifetime=8h  
> > type=transport  
> > left=192.168.1.76  
> > leftsubnet=192.168.1.0/24  
> > leftprotoport=0/0  
> > right=222.222.222.222  
> > rightsubnet=10.196.0.0/17  
> > rightprotoport=0/0
> > ```

Here are the specs provided by the other end that must be met for **Phase #2**:

> encryption algorithm: AES (128 or 256 bit)
>   hash algorithm: SHA
>   local ident1 (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.196.0.0/255.255.128.0/0/0)
>   local ident2 (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.241.0.0/255.255.0.0/0/0)
>   remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (x.x.x.x/x.x.x.x/0/0) (internal network or localhost)
>   Security association lifetime: 4608000 kilobytes/3600 seconds
>   PFS: DH group2

So, finally, what might be the cause of the issue that I am experiencing? Thank you.

Comment: Is NAT-T enabled on the remote peer?

Comment: @ShaneMadden: unsure, but I think it's disabled, as 192.168.x.x was not in use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to get the remote end to enable NAT-T on their end of the connection as well.

IPSec communication cryptographically signs the entire packet - any change to the IP header will invalidate that signature.  NAT works by rewriting the source and/or destination IP fields; having NAT on either end of the connection means that every packet is having the header changed in transit; the source is changed on packets leaving your `192.168` network, and the destination is changed on inbound packets.

NAT-T counteracts this by encapsulating the entire ESP packet in a new UDP packet.  The UDP packet can safely have its headers mangled to the satisfaction of any NAT devices, while the ESP payload will make the entire trip unchanged.  The remote node will need to enable this to protect the packets they're sending your way from the NAT modifications, and you'll both need to be allowing UDP port 4500.

This may not be the only issue in the configuration of the VPN tunnel, but it would certainly explain a malformed payload message; give it a shot, and let us know if any further issues come up!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try your recommendation today and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately, as it turns out, the remote end is not behind a NAT device, so enabling NAT traversal will probably not help in this case. However, UDP port 4500 was indeed not forwarded on our end (as it passed **ipsec verify** with NAT-T enabled) - it is now. Sadly, the outcome is still the same. Is there anything else I can do to debug this?

Comment: As explained in my answer, NAT-T in necessary on both ends of the connection if either end has NAT, because every packet sent by either side will be altered by the NAT on one end.

Answer (score 0):

Support for NAT Traversal is detected in first two messages of ISAKMP. If both devices support NAT-T, then NAT-Discovery is performed in ISKAMP Main Mode message three and four. Since you are past ISAKMP exchange. I don't think this is an issue with NAT-T.

As seen here:

```
003 "x" #1: NAT-Traversal: Result using RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal): i am NATed
004 "x" #1: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=OAKLEY_PRESHARED_KEY cipher=aes_128 prf=oakley_sha group=modp1024}
```

From IPsec logs, it appears to be a bug in either in *Swan version or initiator gateway device.

```
pluto[30868]: "x" #3: STATE_QUICK_R1: sent QR1, inbound IPsec SA installed, expecting QI2
```

Inbound SA is installed. Please note at the end of Quick Mode Message 2, the **Tunnels are ready for use**. The responder is waiting for final confirmation (Message 3). The last message is to check the liveliness of the responder. This just to inform responder that the previous messages were received and processed correctly.